# Template with constant expression: error C2975 with VC++2008

Tags: c++, templates, boost, multi-index

I am trying to use elements of meta programming, but hit the wall with the first trial.
I would like to have a comparator structure which can be used as following:

```
intersect_by<ID>(L1.data, L2.data, "By ID: ");
intersect_by<IDf>(L1.data, L2.data, "By IDf: ");
```

Where:

```
  struct ID{};// Tag used for original IDs
    struct IDf{};// Tag used for the file position  
    //following Boost.MultiIndex examples  
    template<typename Tag,typename MultiIndexContainer>
    void intersect_by(
    const MultiIndexContainer& L1,const MultiIndexContainer&    L2,std::string msg,
      Tag* =0 /* fixes a MSVC++ 6.0 bug with implicit template function parms */
    )
    {
     /* obtain a reference to the index tagged by Tag */

     const typename boost::multi_index::index<MultiIndexContainer,Tag>::type& L1_ID_index=
     get<Tag>(L1);
     const typename boost::multi_index::index<MultiIndexContainer,Tag>::type& L2_ID_index=
     get<Tag>(L2);

      std::set_intersection(
      L1_ID_index.begin(), 
      L1_ID_index.end(), 
      L2_ID_index.begin(), 
      L2_ID_index.end(),
      std::inserter(s, s.begin()), strComparator<Tag>() // Here I get the C2975 error
      );
      }

    template<int N> struct strComparator;
    template<> 
    struct strComparator<0>{
    bool operator () (const particleID& id1, const particleID& id2) const
    {
     return id1.ID<id2.ID;
    }
    };
    template<> 
    struct strComparator<1>{ 
    bool operator () (const particleID& id1, const particleID& id2) const
    {
     return id1.IDf<id2.IDf; 
    }

    };
```

What I am missing?

kind regards
Arman.

Sorry I did not copy the full error message.
Full error:

```
>Compiling...
1>trace_ids.cpp
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(133) : error C2975: 'strComparator' : invalid template argument for 'N', expected compile-time constant expression
1>        c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(47) : see declaration of 'strComparator'
1>        c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(144) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void intersect_by<ID,particlesID_set>(const MultiIndexContainer &,const MultiIndexContainer &,std::string,Tag *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            MultiIndexContainer=particlesID_set,
1>            Tag=ID
1>        ]
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(133) : error C2955: 'strComparator' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>        c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(47) : see declaration of 'strComparator'
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(134) : error C2784: '_OutElem *std::set_intersection(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutElem (&)[_Size],_Pr)' : could not deduce template argument for '_OutElem (&)[_Size]' from 'std::insert_iterator<_Container>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Container=particlesID_set
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(4064) : see declaration of 'std::set_intersection'
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(134) : error C2780: '::std::_Enable_if<!std::_Is_checked_iterator<_OutIt>::_Result,_OutIt>::_Result std::set_intersection(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt)' : expects 5 arguments - 6 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(4004) : see declaration of 'std::set_intersection'
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(134) : error C2780: '_OutElem *std::set_intersection(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutElem (&)[_Size])' : expects 5 arguments - 6 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(3993) : see declaration of 'std::set_intersection'
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(134) : error C2780: '::std::_Enable_if<std::_Is_checked_iterator<_OutIt>::_Result,_OutIt>::_Result std::set_intersection(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt)' : expects 5 arguments - 6 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(3983) : see declaration of 'std::set_intersection'
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(133) : error C2975: 'strComparator' : invalid template argument for 'N', expected compile-time constant expression
1>        c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(47) : see declaration of 'strComparator'
1>        c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(146) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void intersect_by<IDf,particlesID_set>(const MultiIndexContainer &,const MultiIndexContainer &,std::string,Tag *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            MultiIndexContainer=particlesID_set,
1>            Tag=IDf
1>        ]
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(133) : error C2955: 'strComparator' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>        c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(47) : see declaration of 'strComparator'
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(134) : error C2784: '_OutElem *std::set_intersection(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutElem (&)[_Size],_Pr)' : could not deduce template argument for '_OutElem (&)[_Size]' from 'std::insert_iterator<_Container>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Container=particlesID_set
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(4064) : see declaration of 'std::set_intersection'
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(134) : error C2780: '::std::_Enable_if<!std::_Is_checked_iterator<_OutIt>::_Result,_OutIt>::_Result std::set_intersection(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt)' : expects 5 arguments - 6 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(4004) : see declaration of 'std::set_intersection'
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(134) : error C2780: '_OutElem *std::set_intersection(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutElem (&)[_Size])' : expects 5 arguments - 6 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(3993) : see declaration of 'std::set_intersection'
1>c:\documents and settings\arm2arm\mes documents\visual studio 2008\projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\trace_ids.cpp(134) : error C2780: '::std::_Enable_if<std::_Is_checked_iterator<_OutIt>::_Result,_OutIt>::_Result std::set_intersection(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt)' : expects 5 arguments - 6 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(3983) : see declaration of 'std::set_intersection'
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings\arm2arm\Mes documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\mstgraph\trace_ids\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>trace_ids - 12 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Many of us use C++ but not VC++ specifically, so we have no means of knowing what "C2975" means. Please post the full text of the error message, as part of your question, using copy and paste.

Comment: sorry the error messages are in weird format...

Comment: I just added <pre></pre> is it ok?

Comment: @Arman It's not a good idea to use HTML tags when formatting code or errors on SO. Simply select all the text you want to format and click the 1010 button above the text entry area. But it'll do for now.

Comment: thanks, done!BTW are there way to format the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that instead of

```
template<int N> struct strComparator;
```

you want

```
template<typename T> struct strComparator;

template <> struct strComparator<Id>{...}; //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, strComaparator is defined as something like:

```
template <int X>
// rest of definition here
```

When you use such  a template, the thing in the angle brackets must always be a compile time constant. But you use the comparator:

```
strComparator<Tag>()
```

where Tag is a variable - you can't do that.

Comment: but in the boost example we are using following and it works:
 print_out_by<IDf>(L1.data);

where:
template<typename Tag,typename MultiIndexContainer>
void print_out_by(
 const MultiIndexContainer& s,
 Tag* =0 /* fixes a MSVC++ 6.0 bug with implicit template function parms */
)
{
  const typename boost::multi_index::index<MultiIndexContainer,Tag>::type& i=
    get<Tag>(s);
  typedef typename MultiIndexContainer::value_type value_type;
  /* dump the elements of the index to cout */
std::copy(i.begin(),i.end(),std::ostream_iterator<value_type>(std::cout));
}

Comment: @Arman Sorry, that doesn't help. Please confirm the definition of strComparator.